# Infinite loop occuring in linked list

Tags: c, loops, data-structures, linked-list

I have a linked list that contains a method to traverse the list and print out a value of the struct in the linked list.

```
void testLinkedList(LinkedList* list)
    {
        int count = 1;
        LinkedListNode* current = list->head;
        while (current != NULL)
            {
                printf("%d: Label is is %d\n", count, current->data->label);
            current = current->next;
                count++;
            }
        }
```

Have I done something wrong in the loop? It should end when it reaches the last node but this will continue to loop and print out phantom numbers for as long as i allow it to.

EDIT: This is my insertlast() function I use to send to the linked list:

```
void insertLast(LinkedList* list, TinCan* newData)
    {
        int ii = 1;
    LinkedListNode* newNode = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));
    newNode->data = newData;

    //check if queue empty
    if(list->head == NULL)
        {
        list->head = newNode;
        newNode->next=NULL;
        }
    else
        {
        LinkedListNode* current = list->head;
        while (current->next != NULL)
            {
            current = current->next;
            }
        current->next = newNode;
        printf("%d", ii);
        ii++;
        }
}
```

Comment: You probably messed up something when you create/insert into the list and the last item doesn't have its next pointer set to null.

Comment: can you post your LinkListNode structure.

Comment: side note: Your count is wrong the first snippet. It will eval to 1 even on a list that has a NULL head. Hope its value isn't important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to set the next pointer to NULL when creating a new list node:

```
LinkedListNode* newNode = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));
    newNode->data = newData;
    newnode->next = NULL;
```

BTW: the rest of the source can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16331530/905902) related topic.

Comment: No, the cast is terrible. So is the sizeof(TYPE). And the typedefs. But I am not allowed to comment on style, so I am told lately.

Answer (score 2):

have you checked that your LinkedList structure is circular or not? It could happen in case of Circular Linkedlist

Answer (score 1):

This method is correct. check if each node is connected correctly to the next node, and that the last node is connected to NULL.